# Fixed labels in the selection bar of a UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

In the clocks application, the timer screen shows a picker (probably a `UIPicker` in `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer` mode) with some text in the selection bar ("hours" and "mins" in this case).

(edit) Note that these labels are **fixed**: They don't move when the picker wheel is rolling.

Is there a way to show such fixed labels in the selection bar of a standard `UIPickerView` component?

I did not find any API that would help with that. A suggestion was to add a `UILabel` as a subview of the picker, but that didn't work.

---

**Answer**

I followed Ed Marty's advice (answer below), and it works! Not perfect but it should fool people. For reference, here's my implementation, feel free to make it better...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Add pickerView
    self.pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [pickerView release];
    CGSize pickerSize = [pickerView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    #define toolbarHeight           40.0
    CGFloat pickerTop = screenRect.size.height - toolbarHeight - pickerSize.height;
    CGRect pickerRect = CGRectMake(0.0, pickerTop, pickerSize.width, pickerSize.height);
    pickerView.frame = pickerRect;

    // Add label on top of pickerView
    CGFloat top = pickerTop + 2;
    CGFloat height = pickerSize.height - 2;
    [self addPickerLabel:@"x" rightX:123.0 top:top height:height];
    [self addPickerLabel:@"y" rightX:183.0 top:top height:height];
    //...
}

- (void)addPickerLabel:(NSString *)labelString rightX:(CGFloat)rightX top:(CGFloat)top height:(CGFloat)height {
#define PICKER_LABEL_FONT_SIZE 18
#define PICKER_LABEL_ALPHA 0.7
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:PICKER_LABEL_FONT_SIZE];
    CGFloat x = rightX - [labelString sizeWithFont:font].width;

    // White label 1 pixel below, to simulate embossing.
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, top + 1, rightX, height)];
    label.text = labelString;
    label.font = font;
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.opaque = NO;
    label.alpha = PICKER_LABEL_ALPHA;
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    [label release];

    // Actual label.
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, top, rightX, height)];
    label.text = labelString;
    label.font = font;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.opaque = NO;
    label.alpha = PICKER_LABEL_ALPHA;
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    [label release];
}
```

Comment: Does this work for multiple components? I have 3 components, I am trying to add a label to each component. What I have observed is, all the 3 labels are added as subview to the first component. How do I find the view to insert the label subview so that the labels are visible appropriately?

Comment: In short the trick is to use a UIView, which embeds a PickerView and labels. It's impossible to add labels directly to a PickerView in iOS 5.

Comment: Screenshot of the end results plox? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create your picker, create a label with a shadow, and push it to a picker's subview below the selectionIndicator view.

It would look something like this

```
UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(135, 93, 80, 30)] autorelease];
label.text = @"Label";
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake (0,1);
[picker insertSubview:label aboveSubview:[picker.subviews objectAtIndex:5]]; 
//When you have multiple components (sections)...
//you will need to find which subview you need to actually get under
//so experiment with that 'objectAtIndex:5'
//
//you can do something like the following to find the view to get on top of
// define @class UIPickerTable;
// NSMutableArray *tables = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// for (id i in picker.subviews) if([i isKindOfClass:[UIPickerTable class]]) [tables addObject:i];
// etc...
```

-- Pay it forward

Comment: Does this work for multiple components? I have 3 components, I am trying to add a label to each component. What I have observed is, all the 3 labels are added as subview to the first component. How do I find the view to insert the label subview so that the labels are visible appropriately?

Comment: 's excellent answer has been turned into a neat subclass of UIPickerView [here](http://blog.nottoobadsoftware.com/2009/03/a-uipickerview-with-labels/).

Comment: For anyone who wonders why this approaches doesn't work in iOS 5+: You can still add a Label to the PickerView, but it will remain in the background. The method "insertSubview: aboveSubview:" exists, but the subviews are always empty, no matter if the selection bar is activated or how many components you have. The solution is (like shown @squelart's question) to use a view, embed the PickerView as subview and add labels to the view, nicely positioned.

Comment: Bad answer.. never use magic numbers like "objectAtIndex:5", that makes assumptions Apple will never change the structure of a UIPicker.

Comment: Here's a C# version ported from http://blog.nottoobadsoftware.com/iphone-development/a-uipickerview-with-labels/: https://gist.github.com/sfmskywalker/8d750f058cb83e4daca1b6928430e462

Answer (score 11):

I've turned dizy's answer into a category on `UIPickerView` a couple years ago. Just verified that it still works with iOS SDK 4.3, and posting it here. It allows you to add a label (XX hours) and animate changes to this label (e.g. 1 hour -> 3 hours) just like `UIDatePicker` does.

```
// UIPickerView_SelectionBarLabelSupport.h
//
// This file adds a new API to UIPickerView that allows to easily recreate
// the look and feel of UIDatePicker labeled components.
//
// Copyright (c) 2009, Andrey Tarantsov <andreyvit@gmail.com>
//
// Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any
// purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above
// copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES
// WITH REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
// MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR
// ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES
// WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN
// ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF
// OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


// useful constants for your font size-related code
#define kPickerViewDefaultTitleFontSize 20.0f
#define kDatePickerTitleFontSize 25.0f
#define kDatePickerLabelFontSize 21.0f


@interface UIPickerView (SelectionBarLabelSupport)

// The primary API to add a label to the given component.
// If you want to match the look of UIDatePicker, use 21pt as pointSize and 25pt as the font size of your content views (titlePointSize).
// (Note that UIPickerView defaults to 20pt items, so you need to use custom views. See a helper method below.)
// Repeated calls will change the label with an animation effect similar to UIDatePicker's one.
//
// To call this method on viewDidLoad, please call [pickerView layoutSubviews] first so that all subviews
// get created.
- (void)addLabel:(NSString *)label ofSize:(CGFloat)pointSize toComponent:(NSInteger)component leftAlignedAt:(CGFloat)offset baselineAlignedWithFontOfSize:(CGFloat)titlePointSize;

// A helper method for your delegate's "pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:".
// Creates a propertly positioned right-aligned label of the given size, and also handles reuse.
// The actual UILabel is a child of the returned view, use [returnedView viewWithTag:1] to retrieve the label.
- (UIView *)viewForShadedLabelWithText:(NSString *)label ofSize:(CGFloat)pointSize forComponent:(NSInteger)component rightAlignedAt:(CGFloat)offset reusingView:(UIView *)view;

// Creates a shaded label of the given size, looking similar to the labels used by UIPickerView/UIDatePicker.
- (UILabel *)shadedLabelWithText:(NSString *)label ofSize:(CGFloat)pointSize;

@end
```

And the implementation:

```
// UIPickerView_SelectionBarLabelSupport.m
//
// This file adds a new API to UIPickerView that allows to easily recreate
// the look and feel of UIDatePicker labeled components.
//
// Copyright (c) 2009, Andrey Tarantsov <andreyvit@gmail.com>
//
// Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any
// purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above
// copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES
// WITH REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
// MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR
// ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES
// WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN
// ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF
// OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.

#import "UIPickerView_SelectionBarLabelSupport.h"


// used to find existing component labels among UIPicker's children
#define kMagicTag 89464534
// a private UIKit implementation detail, but we do degrade gracefully in case it stops working
#define kSelectionBarClassName @"_UIPickerViewSelectionBar"

// used to sort per-component selection bars in a left-to-right order
static NSInteger compareViews(UIView *a, UIView *b, void *context) {
    CGFloat ax = a.frame.origin.x, bx = b.frame.origin.x;
    if (ax < bx)
        return -1;
    else if (ax > bx)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}


@implementation UIPickerView (SelectionBarLabelSupport)

- (UILabel *)shadedLabelWithText:(NSString *)label ofSize:(CGFloat)pointSize {
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:pointSize];
    CGSize size = [label sizeWithFont:font];
    UILabel *labelView = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)] autorelease];
    labelView.font = font;
    labelView.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    labelView.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
    labelView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    labelView.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    labelView.opaque = NO;
    labelView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    labelView.text = label;
    labelView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    return labelView;
}

- (UIView *)viewForShadedLabelWithText:(NSString *)title ofSize:(CGFloat)pointSize forComponent:(NSInteger)component rightAlignedAt:(CGFloat)offset reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    UILabel *label;
    UIView *wrapper;
    if (view != nil) {
        wrapper = view;
        label = (UILabel *)[wrapper viewWithTag:1];
    } else {
        CGFloat width = [self.delegate pickerView:self widthForComponent:component];

        label = [self shadedLabelWithText:title ofSize:pointSize];
        CGSize size = label.frame.size;
        label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, offset, size.height);
        label.tag = 1;
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        wrapper = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, size.height)] autorelease];
        wrapper.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
        wrapper.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        [wrapper addSubview:label];
    }
    label.text = title;
    return wrapper;
}

- (void)addLabel:(NSString *)label ofSize:(CGFloat)pointSize toComponent:(NSInteger)component leftAlignedAt:(CGFloat)offset baselineAlignedWithFontOfSize:(CGFloat)titlePointSize {
    NSParameterAssert(component < [self numberOfComponents]);

    NSInteger tag = kMagicTag + component;
    UILabel *oldLabel = (UILabel *) [self viewWithTag:tag];
    if (oldLabel != nil && [oldLabel.text isEqualToString:label])
        return;

    NSInteger n = [self numberOfComponents];
    CGFloat total = 0.0;
    for (int c = 0; c < component; c++)
        offset += [self.delegate pickerView:self widthForComponent:c];
    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
        total += [self.delegate pickerView:self widthForComponent:c];
    offset += (self.bounds.size.width - total) / 2;

    offset += 2 * component; // internal UIPicker metrics, measured on a screenshot
    offset += 4; // add a gap

    CGFloat baselineHeight = [@"X" sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:titlePointSize]].height;
    CGFloat labelHeight = [@"X" sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:pointSize]].height;

    UILabel *labelView = [self shadedLabelWithText:label ofSize:pointSize];
    labelView.frame = CGRectMake(offset,
                                 (self.bounds.size.height - baselineHeight) / 2 + (baselineHeight - labelHeight) - 1,
                                 labelView.frame.size.width,
                                 labelView.frame.size.height);
    labelView.tag = tag;

    UIView *selectionBarView = nil;
    NSMutableArray *selectionBars = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        if ([[[subview class] description] isEqualToString:kSelectionBarClassName])
            [selectionBars addObject:subview];
    }
    if ([selectionBars count] == n) {
        [selectionBars sortUsingFunction:compareViews context:NULL];
        selectionBarView = [selectionBars objectAtIndex:component];
    }
    if (oldLabel != nil) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:oldLabel];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(YS_barLabelHideAnimationDidStop:finished:context:)];
        oldLabel.alpha = 0.0f;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
    // if the selection bar hack stops working, degrade to using 60% alpha
    CGFloat normalAlpha = (selectionBarView == nil ? 0.6f : 1.0f);
    if (selectionBarView != nil)
        [self insertSubview:labelView aboveSubview:selectionBarView];
    else
        [self addSubview:labelView];
    if (oldLabel != nil) {
        labelView.alpha = 0.0f;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:oldLabel];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.25];
        labelView.alpha = normalAlpha;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } else {
        labelView.alpha = normalAlpha;
    }
}

- (void)YS_barLabelHideAnimationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(UIView *)oldLabel {
    [oldLabel removeFromSuperview];
}

@end
```

Usage example (in a view controller):

```
- (void)updateFloorLabel {
    NSInteger floor = [self.pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:0] - [self.pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSString *suffix = @"th";
    if (((floor % 100) / 10) != 1) {
        switch (floor % 10) {
            case 1:  suffix = @"st"; break;
            case 2:  suffix = @"nd"; break;
            case 3:  suffix = @"rd"; break;
        }
    }
    [self.pickerView addLabel:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Floor", suffix]
                       ofSize:21
                  toComponent:0
                leftAlignedAt:50
baselineAlignedWithFontOfSize:25];    
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  ...
  [self.pickerView layoutSubviews];
  [self updateFloorLabel];
  ...
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:0] - row];
    return [pickerView viewForShadedLabelWithText:s ofSize:25 forComponent:0 rightAlignedAt:46 reusingView:view];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    [self updateFloorLabel];
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: I tried you solution but get [SettingsViewController pickerView:widthForComponent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance what is wrong? on line  CGFloat width = [self.delegate pickerView:self widthForComponent:component];

Comment: @Andrey, I've been using your great little code here for a while now. Under iOS 7/8, it looks like your selectionBarView hack has indeed gone away, but the code still runs due to your graceful recovery with .6 alpha. What was reason for hack; in other words, what was lost with alpha fallback?  Also, I'm getting an occasional animation crash somewhere in this vicinity. I don't think it's this code, as oldLabel isn't set yet, so no animation, but do you think there might be any problem here?

Answer (score 7):

Let's say we want to implement a picker view for selecting distance, there are 2 columns, one for distance, one for unit, which is km. Then we want the second column to be fixed. We can make it through some delegate methods.

```
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component == 0) {
        return self.distanceItems[row];
    }
    else {
        return @"km";
    }
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 2;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if (component == 0) {
        return [self.distanceItems count];
    }
    else {
    // when it comes to the second column, only one row.
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Now we have this:
[image]

I guess this is the simplest way.

Comment: Initially this solution looks good, but: (1)  the distance between number and unit is too big (any ideas how to make it smaller?), (2) the unit "km" reacts on touches and moves up/down, while the unit in iOS timer is fixed (any ideas how to make it still?)

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 things you can do:

If each row and component in row is a simple text, than you can simply use the default UIPickerView implementation as is, and in your controller implement the following `UIPickerViewDelegate` methods :

- `- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component` to keep track of which row is selected
- and return a different text for the selected row in your implementation of `- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component`

If you need to have something other than text as the differentiator for the selected row, than you basically need to create your own `CustomPickerView` that derives from the `UIPickerView` and then

- First implement the `- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated` and keep track of which row is selected.
- Then implement the `- (UIView *)viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component` to generate a different view for the selected row.

A sample for using the UIPickerView or implementing custom UIPickerView is available in the SDK, called UICatalog.

Comment: Nice trick except for one thing: Using your method, labels are not fixed like "hours" in the Timer picker, as I requested.

It still helps a bit I suppose, at least there's a hint as to what each picker component refers to. But as soon as you actually make it roll, the illusion disappears...

Comment: Also the UICatalog example does not have these fixed labels in the standard or custom UIPickerView's... This may mean that it is probably not provided by the framework. Which seems silly since they have implemented it for the Timer picker!

Answer (score 3):

I received an answer that works well in iOS 7 to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825688/ios7-uipickerview-non-selected-row-curvature-modification-multiple-components), which is a pretty cool [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19826463/463059).

The idea is to create multiple components, and for those label components, specify that it's a single row.  For the embossed look that some people have, you can return NSAttributedStrings with the delegate method:

`- (NSAttributedString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than adding a label within the UIPickerView, just stick it on top of it, as a sibling that overlaps it.  The only thing that's problematic is how to get the same font.  I don't know how to get that embossed look, but maybe somebody else does, in which case, it's not really a problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

To re-create the embossed look for the labels...just create a image with the Text, so that you can easily apply a very similar effect to the text...and then use UIImageViews instead of Labels

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same problem. You can see working example in my custom made time picker published on GitHub:

https://github.com/kgadzinowski/iOSSecondsTimerPicker 

 It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Code sounds extremely familiar to what's found there... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734557/custom-uipickerview-with-three-components-each-showing-label-on-selection-indica ... Putting your copyright everywhere sounds rather .... fishy... won't work on iOS 7 either

Answer (score 0):

Can you show where you define pickerTop and pickerSize?

```
    CGFloat pickerTop = timePicker.bounds.origin.y;
CGSize pickerSize = timePicker.bounds.size;
```

That is what I have, but pickerTop seems to be wrong.

mike

Comment: Code couldn't fit in comment, so I've put it in the answer above. Note the bit of magic (40), this may have to change depending on whether you're using a navigation bar or other things that take screen space above your app... If someone knows a better way, please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

Embossing is explained here: [Adding Emboss to a UILabel in a navigationItem.titleView (as seen with navigationItem.title)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753822/adding-emboss-to-a-uilabel-in-a-navigationitem-titleview-as-seen-with-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

Note that xib editor allows to add child views as well so you can avoid using too much coding and guessing on dimensions.

Comment: Can you please provide some codE?

Answer (score 0):

Horizontally align multiple pickers with no space between them and turn off user interactions for the static columns.

Set a tag on each picker to determine which one is the pickerView in the datasource calls. Static columns will have row counts of one obviously.

This also gives greater control of widths and placement.