# UIDatePicker show only month and day

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

I'd like to have a `UIDatePicker` where the user can pick a month and a day but not the year. I'm aware that leap years have an extra day, so for simplicity, let's throw that day away.

Is there any way to remove the year column or have 2 reels with month/day that act like the `UIDatePicker` (grey out days that don't exist in the selected month)?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use the UIDatePicker class as it stands to do this - The UIDatePicker only supports the following modes

```
typedef enum {
   UIDatePickerModeTime,
   UIDatePickerModeDate,
   UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,
   UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer
} UIDatePickerMode;
```

Create a view and controller that implement the UIPickerViewDelegate and create your own - you may find a little more detail here [Fixed labels in the selection bar of a UIPickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367471/fixed-labels-in-the-selection-bar-of-a-uipickerview)