# Issue with UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone

I want to show only day and month and not year in my date picker. Not sure how to achieve this. Please suggest.

Comment: Your question is tagged [iphone] but you're referring to a Cocoa (Mac OS X) date picker control. Which is it?

Comment: I think he doesn't mean that - I think he means the UIDatePicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll find the answer by Googling this and clicking on the first entry which happens to be from Stackoverflow also: [UIDatePicker show only month and day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407149/iphone-cocoa-uidatepicker-show-only-month-and-day)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the maximumDate property to current date. This disabled the dates from current date.