# Emboss effect in Uilabels

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application for iPhone.I need to give some labels an emboss effect .Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From: [Adding Emboss to a UILabel in a navigationItem.titleView (as seen with navigationItem.title)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753822/adding-emboss-to-a-uilabel-in-a-navigationitem-titleview-as-seen-with-navigation)

```
[myLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
[myLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, -1)];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also try to set alpha value to 0.8 to emphasise the effect