# Creating the embossed look of built in iOS UIPickerViews

Tags: ios, uipickerview

So I can create a static embossed look pretty easily by adding a shadow color and offset to a UILabel, as discussed in multiple [questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753822/adding-emboss-to-a-uilabel-in-a-navigationitem-titleview-as-seen-with-navigatio) on SO.

However, the core system UIPickerViews (e.g. Clock->Timer, Clock->Alarm->Edit) are not static! If you look carefully, they are only embossed while under the selection bar. And half dragging one of the labels out of the selection bar actually results in half the label embossed and the other half not, as seen in this picture here:

[image]

Any ideas how this is achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Use dark text with a light colored shadow. Make sure the text is on a color that is darker than the shadow, but lighter than the text.

[image]

Comment: I thought of this too, but that's not it. Look at the number 2 in the hours component, it's near the bottom where the gradient makes the background darker, but there is no white shadow. You can confirm this easier on a device slowly dragging the numbers down, it is clearly embossed only when under that selector bar.