# how to write text on selection indicator of uipickerview

Tags: iphone

how to write text on selection indicator of uipickerview

Comment: Your question is far too vague. Please revise your question and elaborate.

Comment: Duplicate of [Fixed labels in the selection bar of a UIPickerView](http://stackoverflow.com/q/367471/82505).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach will be just to add `UILabel` with your text over the `UIPickerView`. You only need to find the right coordinates so text will be placed well.

Comment: that must be pretty straightforward, really - simply add UILabel with transparent background above picker, fill you picker with data and then play with label coordinates to find label's best position.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display text on it try adding a UILabel as a subview to the view containing the picker. You just need to get the frame in the right spot - easy with IB, more trial and error through code. The set label to have a clear background. Just update the label value as needed.