# How to set text on UIPicker's selectionbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

I want to set text of "MINS" and "SECS" on the UIPicker's selection bar as shown in the following image. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367471/fixed-labels-in-the-selection-bar-of-a-uipickerview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These tricks might be useful to you:
[how to write text on selection indicator of uipickerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179483/how-to-write-text-on-selection-indicator-of-uipickerview) and [Fixed labels in the selection bar of a UIPickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367471/fixed-labels-in-the-selection-bar-of-a-uipickerview)

Its just simply adding a UILabel with your text over the UIPickerView. You only need to find the right coordinates so text will be placed well.