# Remove Year from date picker in iPhone/iOS app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to remove year from iOS date picker. Need to use in iPhone app.

[image: datepicker example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `UIDatePicker` because  The `UIDatePicker` only supports the following modes

```
typedef enum {
   UIDatePickerModeTime,
   UIDatePickerModeDate,
   UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,
   UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer
} UIDatePickerMode;
```

Create a view and controller that implement the UIPickerViewDelegate and create your own - you may find a little more detail here

[Fixed labels in the selection bar of a UIPickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367471/fixed-labels-in-the-selection-bar-of-a-uipickerview)

Answer (score 2):

This is down to the users phone localization settings... You'll need to create some sort of custom UIPicker if you want to make it the same for all.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and easy way, create your UIPickerView with just two components.