# Android TextView counter with Top/Down Animation

Tags: android, android-animation

We want a Meter animation in `TextView`

[image]

To make it a little more interesting, I want each digit come from top to bottom or bottom to top ?

Right now I using listview for achieving this, I have also tried with `TextSwitcher` but its have a limitation of two child only.

I'm using `getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(0...3...6...6...n)`;

Is there a simple way of doing this? because right now , we need to maintain 3 `ListView` and `Adapter` as well for maintaining this.

Please refer link to more understand this question

[Display StopWatch Timer animated like the petrol pump meter using NSTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314544/display-stopwatch-timer-animated-like-the-petrol-pump-meter-using-nstimer)

Comment: Using 3 `ListView`s is not a good idea. Maybe its better to use 3 `TextView`s (one for each digit) then animate them depending on the counter value.

Comment: Yes i was also thinking the same , but I caught a various of problem during animation,

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`ListView`'s might be good enough solution, but I've implemented it with a custom View (`FrameLayout`), which contains inside 2 `TextView`s, which are animating based on the value changes:

[image]

The idea of code is very basic:

- You pass to `setValue` desired value;
- If it's bigger than current one - start animation from from bottom to top (and vice versa) to increment/decrement current value by 1. Here, we animating two `TextView`s to replace each other;
- In AnimationEnd listener, check if we reached desired value - if not - do one more run (recursively);

  ```
      public class DigitTextView extends FrameLayout {

          private static int ANIMATION_DURATION = 250;
          TextView currentTextView, nextTextView;

          public DigitTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
              super(context, attrs);
              init(context);
          }

          public DigitTextView(Context context) {
              super(context);
              init(context);
          }

          private void init(Context context) {
              LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.digit_text_view, this);
              currentTextView = (TextView) getRootView().findViewById(R.id.currentTextView);
              nextTextView = (TextView) getRootView().findViewById(R.id.nextTextView);

              nextTextView.setTranslationY(getHeight());

              setValue(0);
          }

          public void setValue(final int desiredValue) {
              if (currentTextView.getText() == null || currentTextView.getText().length() == 0) {
                  currentTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d", desiredValue));
              }

              final int oldValue = Integer.parseInt(currentTextView.getText().toString());

              if (oldValue > desiredValue) {
                  nextTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d", oldValue-1));

                  currentTextView.animate().translationY(-getHeight()).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).start();
                  nextTextView.setTranslationY(nextTextView.getHeight());
                  nextTextView.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}
                      @Override
                      public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                          currentTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d", oldValue - 1));
                          currentTextView.setTranslationY(0);
                          if (oldValue - 1 != desiredValue) {
                              setValue(desiredValue);
                          }
                      }
                      @Override
                      public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
                      @Override
                      public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
                  }).start();
              } else if (oldValue < desiredValue) {
                  nextTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d", oldValue+1));

                  currentTextView.animate().translationY(getHeight()).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).start();
                  nextTextView.setTranslationY(-nextTextView.getHeight());
                  nextTextView.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}
                      @Override
                      public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                          currentTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d", oldValue + 1));
                          currentTextView.setTranslationY(0);
                          if (oldValue + 1 != desiredValue) {
                              setValue(desiredValue);
                          }
                      }
                      @Override
                      public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
                      @Override
                      public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
                  }).start();
              }
          }
      }
  ```

And it's XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_blue_rect">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentTextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nextTextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And it's very easy to use:

Add to layout:

```
<klogi.com.myapplication.DigitTextView
    android:id="@+id/digitTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And set Value in code:

```
DigitTextView digitTextView = (DigitTextView) findViewById(R.id.digitTextView);
digitTextView.setValue(5);
```

**Upd:**
Another option to use, from what I see, is to set up a bit customized [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html)

I hope, it helps!

Comment: How can I have value < 1000 and 3 different Boxes to scroll?

Answer (score 16):

Ever since Robinhood won the Material design awards they have open sourced there custom `TextView` just like you are describing.

Check out [Robinhood's Ticker](https://github.com/robinhood/ticker) library

[image]

Comment: Sorry but if there are too many characters, more than could be shown in the container's width, then the whole characters are not shown... It's a bug... And it makes it unusable in production. Don't recommend this plug-in anymore...

Answer (score 3):

This code performs the same animation where number rolldown from top to bottom.

[Rolling-TextView-Animation](https://github.com/kavitamp/Rolling-TextView-Animation)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a handler to get the desired effect. Using this, you won't have to make any custom views.
Create a function **handleTextView** which takes in **initialValue**, **finalValue** and **targetTextview** as arguments. The method is-

```
private void handleTextView(int initialValue, int finalValue, final TextView targetTextview) {
    DecelerateInterpolator decelerateInterpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator(1f);
    final int newInitialValue = Math.min(initialValue, finalValue);
    final int newFinalValue = Math.max(initialValue, finalValue);
    final int difference = Math.abs(finalValue - initialValue);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    for (int count = newInitialValue; count <= newFinalValue; count++) {
      //Time to display the current value to the user.
      int time = Math.round(decelerateInterpolator.getInterpolation((((float) count) / difference)) * 100) * count;
      final int finalCount = ((initialValue > finalValue) ? initialValue - count : count);
      handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          targetTextview.setText(finalCount.toString());
        }
      }, time);
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE:** 
Option 2- You can use a value animator as well-

```
private void handleTextView(int initialValue, int finalValue, final TextView  textview) {

    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialValue, finalValue);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(1500);

    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

            textview.setText(valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString());

        }
    });
    valueAnimator.start();

}
```

By using this method we do not need to do any math.