# DatePicker with empty option in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

I want to use date picker with the empty option. Like if user don't want to select day, month or year there will be an option of "-"(empty).

**Here is an image for better understanding**

[image: Here is an image for better understanding]

Comment: That's not possible using UIDatePicker, instead you can use UIPickerView to get what you want. You can set custom titles using titleForRow function.

Comment: @MeeranTariq if you add it as an answer I'll vote it up :)

Comment: **Refer this one** https://stackoverflow.com/a/8501704/10150796

Comment: @AhmadF i just added that. :P

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the values of UIDatePicker. If you want custom values to be displayed on rows, you can use UIPickerView. Sample code for showing months along with "-" is:

```
let months: [String] = ["-" ,"January", "February", "March",
                        "April", "May", "June",
                        "July", "August", "September",
                        "October", "November", "December"]

let pickerView: UIPickerView = UIPickerView()

pickerView.delegate = self
pickerView.dataSource = self

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return months.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return months[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
// do whatever you want when specific row is selected
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For such way you need to use not **DATE PICKER VIEW** for this way you can use **Picker View**, and manually setup date.

Ex:

```
var monthsArray = ["-", "May", "June", "...", "December"]
var yearsArray = ["-", "2018", "2017", "2016", "...."]
var daysArray = ["1", "2", "-", "3", "4"]
```