# UIDatePicker in UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer mode: how to change to minutes and seconds mode?

Tags: iphone, storyboard, uidatepicker

I added UIDatePicker in my storyboard, and set mode to CountDownTimer.
It shows hours and minutes only, but what i need is minutes and seconds mode.
I don't need hour column, need minute and seconds columns.
I try to change interval, but it's minimum value is 1 minute.
Is it possible? How can I do this?

Comment: you can create a datasource by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a datasource for you minute-seconds picker. It has two Components: minute and seconds. You have to implement some methods in `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource` Protocols.

Apple's sample code [UICatalog.app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007710) is for your reference. You can find there is a sample for how to create a customized picker.

Comment: Is that mean I should use UIPickerview, not UIDatePicker?

Comment: @ttotto yes, as the datePickerMode does not have a type you want.

Comment: thanks, then I want to add "minute" and "second" on the selection bar of the pickerview. Do you know how can I do this?

Comment: @ttotto take a look at the sample how to create a custom picker.

Comment: Of course, I reviewed the code and make it, but there is no that feature. Do you know selection bar of the picker control? And have you ever seen the selection bar of the UIDatePikcer in UIDateCountDownMode? If you see it, you can find the "Hour" and "Minute" string on the selection bar.

Comment: @ttotto Is UIDateCountDownMode what you need? I don't think so. As I never use that mode, but only read the doc for it. What you have to do is to custom your own picker. The code in the sample is not exactly what you need, but you can refer to it and learn how to implement the  methods in UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource Protocols.

Comment: thanks. you don't understand me yet. I found a solution at the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367471/fixed-labels-in-the-selection-bar-of-a-uipickerview.