# Set UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer

Tags: iphone, ios, timer, uidatepicker, countdown

I have a button in my view with the UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer.  How do I actually get it to start counting down?  Examples would be fantastic.

Comment: see details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501793/uidatepicker-in-uidatepickermodecountdowntimer-mode-how-to-change-to-minutes-an

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a datasource for you minute-seconds picker. It has two Components: minute and seconds. You have to implement some methods in UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource Protocols.

Apple's sample code [UICatalog.app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007710) is for your reference. You can find there is a sample for how to create a customized picker.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to create a data source.  Also, within the sample code you provided, there is no button or way to start the countdown.  Could you provide a more detailed explanation for how to create the datasource?  I've got the required methods from UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerviewDataSource in my implementation.  

Thanks for the help you've provided so far.

Comment: Apple's sample Xcode project doesn't seem to include a date picker configured with the `datePickerMode` property set to `UIDatePicker.Mode.countDownTimer` --at least not that I can find.