# How can i display the UIDatePicker with HH:MM:SS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

How can i display the `UIDatePicker` with format `HH:MM:SS` as there is no mode for this in `UIDatePicker`.Currently it is showing the date and time.I get to know that ,I have to use `NSDate` format .But I don't know how to use it.

I need to do this  As I am getting the value in a format `HH:MM:SS`. need to display it on the picker and then change to any value after that have to save it .

below is the code that I use to create the custom picker.

```
CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0,self.view.bounds.size.height-250,0,0);
UIDatePicker *myPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
myPicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];
myPicker.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
myPicker.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
```

How and where can I use the formatter so that it display the following format .

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: Please check these two links 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734557/custom-uipickerview-with-three-components-each-showing-label-on-selection-indica and 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999575/uipickerview-that-looks-like-uidatepicker-but-with-seconds might helps you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are following types of modes available in UIDatePicker:

```
UIDatePickerModeTime,
UIDatePickerModeDate,
UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,
UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer
```

With the following you can show time:

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
```

**But both date and time can not be shown.**

What you can do is either subclass `UIPickerView` or in after selecting the Date, prompt user to select time using the above pickerMode.

Answer (score 2):

You can only use UIDatePicker to display the set of standard formats.

If you want to display anything else you will have to use a custom UIPickerView.