# Add fixed UILabel in UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I saw a [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367471/fixed-labels-in-the-selection-bar-of-a-uipickerview) and I tried a few options but non worked.

I would like to create a UIPickerView like the one below, (fixed labels inches and feet) but those wouldn't appear:

[image]
I create the UIImagePicker like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   _picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
   CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 216);
    pickerView.frame = pickerFrame;
    pickerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.hidden = YES;
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
    [textField setInputView:pickerView];
    textField.delegate = self;

    [pickerView removeFromSuperview];
   _picker.hidden = YES;
}


- (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (textView.tag==1){ //field for the uipickerview
        _picker.hidden = NO;
        [self addPickerLabel:@"Feet" rightX:114 top:342 height:21];
        [self addPickerLabel:@"Inches" rightX:241 top:342 height:21];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)addPickerLabel:(NSString *)labelString rightX:(CGFloat)rightX top:(CGFloat)top height:(CGFloat)height {
#define PICKER_LABEL_FONT_SIZE 18
#define PICKER_LABEL_ALPHA 0.7
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:PICKER_LABEL_FONT_SIZE];
    CGFloat x = rightX - [labelString sizeWithFont:font].width;

    // White label 1 pixel below, to simulate embossing.
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, top + 1, rightX, height)];
    label.text = labelString;
    label.font = font;
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.opaque = NO;
    label.alpha = PICKER_LABEL_ALPHA;
    [_picker addSubview:label];


    // Actual label.
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, top, rightX, height)];
    label.text = labelString;
    label.font = font;
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.opaque = NO;
    label.alpha = PICKER_LABEL_ALPHA;
    [_picker addSubview:label];
}
```

The picker appears, but without the fixed labels of inches and feet.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the already implemented great component:

https://github.com/brunow/ActionSheetPicker2

Which provides a multicolumn picker view and I simply changed the text and the amount of columns

Comment: use 'ActionSheetPicker-3.0', '~> 1.3.10'  http://skywinder.github.io/ActionSheetPicker-3.0

Comment: maybe - I wrote this answer 1.5 years ago :) but thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Move this lines to `viewDidLoad` and try it.Labels need to be added
   once.Not always when textfield did begin editing

   ```
   [self addPickerLabel:@"Feet" rightX:114 top:342 height:21];
   [self addPickerLabel:@"Inches" rightX:241 top:342 height:21];
   ```
2. Log the frame of both the label and set it correct if it appears wrong

   ```
   NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(label.frame));
   ```

Comment: Check 2 and see the result

Comment: {{183, 343}, {241, 21}}
{{183, 342}, {241, 21}}

Answer (score 0):

Your UIPickerView has height of 216, but you put the labels at height 342. This might be the reason you can't see them.

Edit:
Try replacing the lines where you make the labels to

```
    [self addPickerLabel:@"Feet" rightX:114 top:98 height:21];
    [self addPickerLabel:@"Inches" rightX:241 top:98 height:21];
```

Comment: CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 216); Clearly frame of pickerView is 216. Your labels are simply out of bounds of their superView.

Comment: I tried your edited code  [self addPickerLabel:@"Feet" rightX:114 top:98 height:21];
    [self addPickerLabel:@"Inches" rightX:241 top:98 height:21]; but it wouldn't help

Comment: But did you move them to viewDidLoad as @Lithu T.V suggested?

Comment: Yes. I did move them to viewDidLoad

Comment: Does it work if you remove the [pickerView removeFromSuperview]; line from viewDidLoad? Also, I see you have _picker (a property) and also use pickerView. Is this a typo or are they two separate objects?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36248/discussion-between-johnyu-and-odelya)

Comment: I decided to use https://github.com/brunow/ActionSheetPicker2 which has a the fixed label implemented already. Thanks for the help!